# How to write a cron job for only 10 days?

Tags: unix, cron

I need to write a cron job that runs daily, but for only 10 days and stops after 
executing for 10 days.

As soon as I write a job, it should start and run for 10 days daily.

Comment: So, you'll need to specify the month, the days of the month, and the time at which the job is to run; you don't care about the day of the week on which it runs.  If your cron supports ranges (10-19), it's easy; if it doesn't, you have to write the days out longhand.  If the 10 days spans across 2 months, you need 2 entries, one for the last N days of the first month and the second for the first 10-N days of the second month.  Go to it!  Remember to delete the entry before the same period next year.  What's the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

Do: `0 10 5-15 1 * command`

for more information on crontab [visit](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm)

[image: structure]

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you finished with the script, save to particular path. After that set a cronjob for that job.

Eg:
filename : /home/script/Job1

set cron:

*** 00 10-20 * * /home/script/Job1**

If suppose you are writing you job on 10th, then another 10 days it will run as my crontab at 12.00 A.M.